# Kotlin: Cannot get FileReader to find file

Tags: android, kotlin

For an Android App, I'm trying to use the FilerReader function to read my csv file, but after trying everything I cannot get to find my file. I'm using Android studios on a Mac.

Below is my code inside OnCreate():

```
val filereader = BufferedReader(FileReader("sgsraagadata.csv"))
```

I have tried placing the csv file inside assets & all resource folders including a raw-type folder.

Similar posts on Stackoverflow suggests that I find the directory that is being searched so that I can put the csv file in that directory. But when I follow their instructions below is what I get.

When I use:

```
println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))
```

It prints "/". And when I use:

```
println(File(".").getAbsoluteFile())
```

It prints "/."

Given these printed outputs, where should I put the csv file?

*Also added an image showing csv file in assets folder as per suggestion in comments. Result is still an file not found error.
[image]

Comment: How are you running your application?

Comment: *Am I doing this right?* doing what? You haven't posted your code, haven't said where your CSV file is located, haven't said how you run your app, from which directory you're running it... How could we know? You can put your file anywhere, provided you use the actual path of the file to read it.

Comment: Hey, I've expanded on my question. Plz take another read and lmk if you can provide some help. Thx

Comment: You still haven't said how you run your app, which is essential for understanding why the current directory is the root directory of your disk when you run it.

Comment: I conclude from what you added that you're writing an Android application. That's a critical information. Tag your question with the android tag, and make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Put your file in `assets` folder and open it like this:

```
val file = context.assets.open("sgsraagadata.csv")
val isr = InputStreamReader(file)
val reader = BufferedReader(isr)

var line = reader.readLine()
while (line != null) {
    // do something with the line
    line = reader.readLine()    
}
```

supply a valid Context or inside an activity you can omit it.

Comment: Hey, yup this does do the trick! but do you know why FileReader can't find my file? Not knowing is eating away at my brain!

Comment: Where did you put the file and it couldn't be found?

Comment: I tried putting it in 1. res folder 2. all the default folders within res 3. a raw folder I created within res 4. assets folder

Comment: Why? this type of files must reside in assets, see this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

Comment: FileReader couldn't find the csv file inside Assets Folder either.

Comment: @JohnPaoletto the assets folder is not a regular folder in a device. It is included in your app. The way to access it and its contents is as I describe in my answer.

Comment: @JohnPaoletto the `assets` folder is a subfolder of `app/src/main/`

Comment: Yup just tried it there again, and still not found. I've added a screenshot in my question to show the code & file as well. If you get the time, plz take a look and see if I'm missing something! Chrz @forpas